# Prestashop - custom template link

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I'm starting with "**PrestaShop**" and I just can't figure out, how to put a link in template to custom page I created in CMS module... I thought, there might be some easy way, as there is in WordPress, like "`get_permalink(ID)`", but there's nothing like this and I can't find anything about this anywhere and it just drives me mad.

So, here's the deal, I've got a custom template, and there are some top links, like "*About Us*". I've created this page in CMS and it has ID "`6`".

How do I make this bloody "PrestaShop" to generate a link to this page in my template file?

```
<a href="WHAT GOES HERE">About</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the "WHAT goes here" is just the url you want your link drives the client to when clicking on that link.

You need to understand a little minimum of HTML for this I guess. Check [html tag a meaning](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_a.asp)  .

Prestashop has a fairly good and extensive documentation. Two and half seconds googling drives me [here](http://www.ecartservice.net/06082009/customising-prestashop-module-templates/), just like answering your question it looks like.

Comment: Thats brilliant :), ok pal, maybe I explained myself wrong - is there inner function in Prestahshop, that will generate friendly url according to page ID I give to this function?

Comment: Ok sorry. Then 2 more googling seconds drive to [this](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/viewthread/90401/configuring___using_prestashop/cms_links_dont_work_when_using_friendly_url__1_dot_4_rc2) and [that](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/viewthread/44175/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for SMARTY template tags and custom variables defined for Prestashop specifically. The one the you probably need is `{$base_dir}` which will be translated to `http://www.yoursite.com/` obviously with appropriate protocol (non-secure HTTP or secured HTTPS).

After that, you only need to include page URL, which you can get from Admin->Tools->CMS section.

If I find any specific tags that you can use to call the content, I will update my post here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{$link->getCMSLink('YOUR_PAGE_ID')}">Your Text</a>
```